# PHP Mongodb driver 1.5: how to use connection pool?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using PHPLIB 1.4 + PHP mongodb-1.5(PECL). How to set up connection pool? I searched but all results are for older version.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP driver uses [libmongoc](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver)'s single-threaded client mode, which does not implement connection pools.

See [mongo-php-driver: issues#688](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/688):

> Connection pools should not be needed for any single-threaded
>   application, unless you're using an async PHP framework (e.g. Amp,
>   ReactPHP). In those cases, you'd probably need to implement your own
>   driver as we provide no way to integrate libmongoc's IO with a PHP
>   event loop. Multi-threaded PHP applications (e.g. pthreads, forking)
>   are not supported by the driver.

Instead of connection pooling, the PHP driver uses connection and topology persistence since version 1.2.0+.

When [MongoDB\Driver\Manager::__construct()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php) is invoked, a hash is created from its arguments (i.e. URI string and array options). The driver will attempt to find a previously persisted `libmongoc` client object for that hash. If an existing client cannot be found for the hash, a new client will be created (and persisted for future use).

See more information [MongoDB PHP Connection Handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.connection-handling.php).